# Ubuntu suddenly goes Black Screen

Tags: 22.04, crash, nvidia-geforce, reset

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04. But yesterday my os started to randomly go black screen.
When that happens I have no longer access to my computer anyway but forced-shutdown by start button. Why could that happens and how to fix it?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Does CTRL+ ALT+ F3 Take you to a tty3 session?

Comment: No nothing happens when screen goes black.

Comment: Try booting into an install media and click on try ubuntu instead of install ubuntu. then mount the drive using disks and see the `<DEVICE_ID>/var/log/boot.log` . paste the output in your question(by editing it).

Comment: I found the file but it has approximately 6700 lines. Should I paste it anyway or what should I do/

Comment: Copy and paste into a new paste on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and share the link so I can try to find what's wrong. I'll try my best to solve your problem.

Comment: There is also a [boot repair tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) which boots of your USB and repairs your disk.

Comment: [pastebinlink](https://pastebin.com/yxSzk1Un) .I also thank you for your attention.

Comment: What's your graphics card? The log says that it failed to find your graphics card.

Comment: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile. I have installed a driver from additional drivers.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for the late response, but I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1:

- Boot from the Installation media and select Try Ubuntu
- Mount your ubuntu disk using the Disks app
- Enable safe graphics

```shell
sudo apt install vim
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Then add `nomodeset` at the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> then release.
The Type `wq` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>  and then run `sudo update-grub`

- Reboot into the Current Ubuntu Installation and Reinstall the Driver
- Do `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`, remove `nomodeset`, then `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

### Solution 2 (If the first method doesn't work):

- Download the [boot repair live cd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) ISO and then flash into a USB
- Boot into it and once you boot, there should be a screen.
- Click on recommended repair and follow the steps if any.
- After it finished, reboot and your done.

### Final Resort(If none of them works):

- Back up your data using file backup app and once it opens one of the buttons it should say "create my first backup" and that's the button you want to press.
- Reinstall ubuntu using the live Ubuntu Reinstall media.
- Restore your backup by following the last part of this [guide](https://adamtheautomator.com/ubuntu-backup/).

I hope this helps.