# Ubuntu 22.04 suddenly goes Black Screen after apt upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, freeze

I have similar issue for my ubuntu:
[Ubuntu suddenly goes Black Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443744/ubuntu-suddenly-goes-black-screen)

The system can normally boot into the GUI and I can use it for few hours. It just suddenly went black screen and it happened couple of times since my last update/upgrade.
However, I tried take control this morning by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 and I found login prompt pop up. So, it is not a total system crash. It seems like some desktop package crash.

Does anyone know how to do inspection and fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: reinstall gnome-shell, ubuntu-desktop, gdm3, gnome-session, no luck.

Comment: systemctl restart display-manager can get into the GUI but all previous session lost. e.g. Firefox webpage closed. text-editor file closed...

Comment: looking to reinstall nvidia driver and switch to other dm.

Comment: reinstall nvidia driver and switch to lightdm, no luck. trying X.org Nouveau display.

Comment: Please do not add comments containing additional information about your issue: add them directly to your question. Otherwise, it becomes difficult to sift through comments that are comments and comments that are new information. Thanks